# Receiving items from reactive stream SubmissionPublisher

Tags: reactive-programming, java-9, reactive-streams

I was trying out some of the new features in Java 9. So I put together a test to have a publisher, emitting numbers at a given rate. I also implemented a Subscriber to listen to those publications and just print them to console.

Although I might not fully understand how to use this Api, because the `onNext()` method is not printing anything and `getLastItem()` only returns 0.

The only part that seems to work is the `onSubscribe()` which correctly initialises the `lastItem` variable.

```
@Test
public void testReactiveStreams(){
    //Create Publisher
    SubmissionPublisher<Integer> publisher = new SubmissionPublisher<>();

    //Register Subscriber
    TestIntegerSubscriber subscriber = new TestIntegerSubscriber();
    publisher.subscribe(subscriber);

    assertTrue(publisher.hasSubscribers());

    //Publish items
    System.out.println("Publishing Items...");

    List.of(1,2,3,4,5).stream().forEach(i -> {
        publisher.submit(i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // blah
        }
    });
    assertEquals(5, subscriber.getLastItem());

    publisher.close();
}


private class TestIntegerSubscriber implements Flow.Subscriber<Integer> {

    private int lastItem;
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription subscription) {
        System.out.println("Subscribed");
        lastItem = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Integer item) {
        System.out.println("Received : "+item);
        lastItem += 1; // expect increment by 1
        assertTrue(lastItem == item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        // nothing for the moment
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        System.out.println("Completed");
    }

    public int getLastItem(){
        return lastItem;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong in my test please? I would expect the test to print those numbers and return 5 as last item.

I have to say I am only using Observables and Subjects in Angular2, although they seems easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

The Flow API implements a feature called *backpressure* ([explained here in the context of RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure)), which means the publisher should not be able to overwhelm the subscriber by publishing items faster than it can process them. The way JDK 9 implements that is by having the subscriber request items from the subscription.

For your test, the `TestIntegerSubscriber` should request items `onSubscription`, let's say 10, and keep track of how often `onNext` has been called, so it can request more once the 10 items were pushed.

I wrote [a section about the Flow API](https://www.sitepoint.com/ultimate-guide-to-java-9/#reactivestreams) that goes into a little more detail. It also describes the interaction between publisher, subscriber, and subscription:

1. Create a `Publisher` and a `Subscriber`.
2. Subscribe the subscriber with `Publisher::subscribe`.
3. The publisher creates a `Subscription` and calls `Subscriber::onSubscription` with it so the subscriber can store the subscription.
4. At some point *the subscriber* calls `Subscription::request` to request a number of items.
5. The publisher starts handing items to the subscriber by calling `Subscriber::onNext`. It will never publish more than the requested number of items.
6. The publisher might at some point be depleted or run into trouble and call `Subscriber::onComplete` or `Subscriber::onError`, respectively.
7. The subscriber might either continue to request more items every now and then or cut the connection by calling `Subscription::cancel`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some more research and I can see the code can be made to work by adding a `Subscription` member in the `Subscriber` implementation as follows:

```
public class MySubscriber<T> implements Subscriber<T> {  
  private Subscription subscription;
```

...

```
@Override
        public void onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription subscription) {
            this.subscription = subscription;
            System.out.println("Subscribed");
            subscription.request(1);
            lastItem = 0;
        }
```

...

```
  @Override
        public void onNext(Integer item) {
            System.out.println("Received : "+item);
            lastItem += 1; // expect increment by 1
            assertTrue(lastItem == item);
            subscription.request(1);
        }
```

where the `subscription.request(1);`  I think it means I am consuming 1 item from the publisher. I don't know...actually would be good if someone clarifies it to me.

Comment: 0
down vote
The call to subscription.request(1) means subscriber has room to accept I message from the publisher. After that call publisher calls to subscriber.onNext() once and waits subscriber to allow him to put more data.